# Define a table in Express with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, oop

I want to define the structure of a table (object) in a mysql 8.0.15 database in a project created with Express (Node.js v8.10.0)

When I was using Mongo and mongoose I was creating the schema of an object (for example a dish in a social network) in the models folder in a class called **dishes.js**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const commentSchema = new Schema({
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        required: true

}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

I'm struggling to find the analog solution for mysql. Anyone has a preferred library and methodolgy to replicate this using mysql?

Answer (score 0):

use sequelize- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize

Use can do anything with this ORM. I have used it to design a complete project